# Upload a chain through PLESK where there are only fields for the certificate and the authority?

Tags: security-certificate, plesk, godaddy

I have a free certificate bundle which include a root, intermediate, server and CA crt files. I am trying to use this 3rd-party certificate in a GoDaddy PLESK hosted solution and have the option to upload the certificates as text into two fields: certificate and certificate CA text field. So far I have uploaded the server certificate and CA certificate, however an SSL check confirms the chain is incomplete and some users experience a certificate error in Chrome.

How do I upload the entire chain into these two fields? I understand I can copy the text value of the crt files one after the other in a single field. Which certificate value goes into which field in what order?

Answer (score 1):

You should concatenate all (that is intermediate - but you may have one or more of them - and CA) certificates and put it in "certificate CA" field, while you put the server certificate in the "certificate" field.

Note that the CA certificate ("root" certificate) is technically not needed in "certificate CA" field (which then introduces quite a misleading term) because clients should already have locally the CA (root) certificate, hence only the intermediate(s) should be needed. But adding the root one should not have drawbacks either.

The order is normally not relevant.

The latest TLS specifications (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8446#section-4.4.2) say this:

> Because    certificate validation requires that trust anchors be
> distributed    independently, a certificate that specifies a trust
> anchor MAY be    omitted from the chain, provided that supported peers
> are known to    possess any omitted certificates.

and

> Note: Prior to TLS 1.3, "certificate_list" ordering required each
> certificate to certify the one immediately preceding it; however,
> some implementations allowed some flexibility.  Servers sometimes
> send both a current and deprecated intermediate for transitional
> purposes, and others are simply configured incorrectly, but these
> cases can nonetheless be validated properly.  For maximum
> compatibility, all implementations SHOULD be prepared to handle
> potentially extraneous certificates and arbitrary orderings from any
> TLS version, with the exception of the end-entity certificate which
> MUST be first.

(you do not need to care about the last part, since this is done automatically properly by the server software as you have two fields, to clearly separate the server certificate from the "others".)

That way the server should properly send on one side its certificate, and separately the chain of trust needed by clients to ascertain your server certificate is valid and descending from some known CA they trust.